# C#: Access function of another class when having to use a default constructor and making it static is not an option

Tags: c#, android

I am working on a little app that includes a broadcast receiver.
Broadcast receivers HAVE to HAVE a default constructor. Don't ask me why...

Anyway, This is it:

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
public class IntentReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
     public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
     {
         if (AudioManager.ActionAudioBecomingNoisy.Equals(intent.Action))
         {
            Activity_Player.Instance.PlayOrPauseLogic();
         }
     }
 }
```

The problem is, that when this function fires (becoming noisy means someone unplugged the headset) I need to be able to stop the current music playing.

In my main class, I have a MediaPlayer object called mediaplayer. I now need to call this mediaplayer object with the ".Stop()" prompt.

This means however, that I cannot just create a new object from my class and then call Stop() on this media player, since this would not affect the currently playing media player.

I can also not hand the media player over into broadcast recevier, since the constructor needs to be the default one.

Lastley, making the mediaplayer object static is also NOT an option for many reasons now.

So what can I do?

What I did now is make a single instance of my activity and THEN call stop on this instance. This is a very bad solution since it causes memory leaks and I need to get rid of it.

Please help me.
Thank you! :)

Comment: Decoupled messaging, pub/sub, event aggregator ?

Comment: I have never heard of neither... which one is best I shall google it.

Comment: Why is `static` not an option?

Comment: Well, I need to call a complecated method called "playorpauselogic()" which itself calls many differenft functions. if playorpauslogic() would be static I wouldnt be able to call the other functions unless they are static. this would leed to everything having to be static...

Comment: OK, so you mean the _method_ can't be `static`. What if you had a global (`static`) variable so that the object was effectively a singleton?

Comment: This is kinda what I did, but i always read this is bad practice?

Comment: I actually solved the issue by not registereing the broadcast reveicer in code but in manifest. this ment i can give it any constructor i like making this all a lot easier :)

Comment: `This is kinda what I did, but i always read this is bad practice?` Well, if you really need a global variable then using it is acceptable.